# Javascript Phonegap - Saving all <li> to avoid wasting time

Tags: javascript, html, list, session, cordova

I'm iterating my local database and adding each item of a table to a  list. As I have over 3,000 rows in that table, it takes like 10 seconds to append all those items. I tried taking out jQuery Mobile, but it still takes a long time.

For example, I have my customers list, I wait 10 seconds to get the 3,000 of them, then, I touch one of them to see the details, and when I go back, it starts appending the 3,000 all over again and have to wait that time again and again.

Is there a way to do that only the first time? I tried saving the  html to a session variable but also takes a long time.

This is how I have it:

```
function getProducts(){
        var query ="SELECT name FROM person";

        db.transaction(function (tx){
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results){
                var len = results.rows.length;


                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                        $('#customers').append("<li>" + results.rows.item(i).name + 
                        "</li>");
                    }

            }, callBack);
        }, callBack);
    }
```

Comment: I'd start with not loading all of them... Pagination is your friend.

Comment: Either paginate or cache the page as HTML and update at set intervals.

Comment: I'd recommend looping and through and concatenating each `li` onto the end of a string.  Then once the string is built, you only have to do a single `.append()`.  That doesn't necessarily solve your problem of only getting the data once but definitely takes a load off doing 3000 `.append()`'s

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing all the appending within document.createDocumentFragment and then append that to the live DOM only after you've completed the loop that builds each LI.